# Countable Set & Formal Grammar

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, computational-complexity, computability, formal-languages

We know set A is countable if A is finite or in a one-to-one mapping to natural numbers.

I try to summarize my though. I think the following proposition is true. suppose $\Sigma$ is arbitrary alphabet. every one would please help me and add some hints for each one, or if I'm wrong correct me !! thanks to all.

1) Each arbitrary Language on  $\Sigma$ is Countable.

2) the set of all language from  $\Sigma$ is Countable.

3) for  Each arbitrary Language on  $\Sigma$  we have a generative formal grammar.

4)  Each arbitrary Language on  $\Sigma$ that generated by formal grammar, is recursive.

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ really arbitrary or shouldn't we assume it is countable?

Comment: Dear @HagenvonEitzen, $\Sigma$ is arbitrary finite alphabet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26201270/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/957967/14578, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/908743/14578

Answer (score 1):

1. If $\Sigma$ is any finite alphabet (or even countably infinite), then $\Sigma^*$ is countable, hence so is any language on $\Sigma$
2. Let $a\in\Sigma$ be an arbitrary letter. Then for any subset $A\subseteq\mathbb N$, we have the language $\{\,a^n\mid n\in A\,\}$. As there are uncoutably many subsets of $\mathbb N$, there are uncountably many languages.
3. Grammars are allowed to have only finitely many rules and metavariabables, hence there are only countably many grammars - less than there are languages.
4. Indeed, one can transform a grammar into a Turing machine that shows recursiveness.

Comment: Dear Hagen, you means 1, 3 and 4 is True ?

Comment: I try lots of note's today. I think just 1 is true...

Comment: Dear @Hagen, please let me know about my comment !!

Comment: I suggest that 1 and 4 are true.

Comment: I think 4 is false? there exist a recursively enumerable language that is not recursive.